# How to create a namespace I can import from python

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have written a python package, called `sugarplot`, which contains an `__init__.py`:

```
from sugarplot.test import testing
```

Where I have a python module `testing.py` in the `sugarplot/test/` directory. Say this file has a function `some_function` which I would like to import. What I would LIKE to do (and doesn't seem to work) is to do the following, in a python interpreter / or another script:

```
from sugarplot.testing import some_function
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sugarplot.testing'
```

However, running the following:

```
import sugarplot
print(sugarplot.testing)
```

Yields:

```
<module 'sugarplot.test.testing' from '/Users/jordan.e/Google Drive/GTD/PhD/Software/sugarplot/sugarplot/test/testing.py'>
```

So the module is VERY CLEARLY there, but for some reason I can't import directly from it. Why is this? How do I import my function (`some_function`) into the `sugarplot` namespace so that I *can* import it with:

```
from sugarplot.testing import some_function
```

I know I'm probably missing something fundamental about how imports work, but I don't know what it is and I haven't been able to find an answer.

EDIT:
The following works (which follows the directory structure):

```
from sugarplot.test.testing import some_func
```

How do I force what I *actually* want to work, inedpendent of the directory structure? I thought importing `testing` would create a namespace in the `sugarplot` module called `testing` which knows nothing about the directory structure.

Inspecting the module, it looks like the following:

```
<module 'pkg.test.testing' from '/Users/jordan.e/Google Drive/GTD/PhD/Software/sandbox/pkg/test/testing.py'>
```

Comment: It's not `sugarplot.testing`, it's `sugarplot.test.testing`.

Comment: I know, I'm saying I *want* it to be sugarplot.testing. How do I make it sugarplot.testing?

Comment: One easy way would be by not nesting it in the `test` directory of your package.